# History of interpolation methods - Newton

Tags: calculus, newton

I'm interested in reading more about how Newton developed his method of interpolation and also the proofs he developed to this topic.  I'm currently reading "Analysis by its history" which gives a good first insight and mentions "The Mathematical Papers of Isaac Newton - volume 8" as a source, this seems, however, not be available as a pdf or ebook and only as a paperback version. Can anyone recommend me some resources where I can read more about this topic which are eventually accessible for free?

Comment: A decent nearby library, or an inter-library loan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research I stumbled across [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41137708?refreqid=excelsior%3A0cbf6a33e7b2d5c845e68465ba549c09&seq=1) paper which might be a good starting point. As often in mathematics, Newton discovered his method of *divided differences* through pattern finding whereby the paper gives a slightly adjusted approach after some examination of Newton's thoughts which will give you a good idea why his method works.